# Open file with specific extension from Safari in my iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, uti

I configured that my app can open files with a specific extension (SFL in the example below). It works well when i try to open files from email attachment in the mail app or from other apps. However, if i try to open from Safari it does not work (for example, from the Google Drive web site).
The file is automatically opened in the browser as text file. How can i open the files in my app?

[image]

Comment: Anyone got the solution ? I also having the same issue. Please Help!

Comment: Eric, have you got the solution for this? If yes, please share..

Answer (score 0):

For opening files with mime type "plain/text" and "gwe" extension, for instance, eg "myfile.gwe"

In your info.plist:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>public.gwe</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.gwe</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>



    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>gwe custom file</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>public.gwe</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>gwe</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```